# How to Find Candy Machine V2 on SolScan

Tags: blockchain, solana, nft

So Guys, i'm really noob at blockchain thins, but i'm trying my best to learn. I would love to know how to find the Candy Machine V2 on SolScan, i see a lot of bots can mint with this Candy Machine ID, but i don't how to find it. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the CMid using an NFT by fetching the first tx that the NFT has (the oldest one) and checking the fifth instruction, then the first account on this instruction is the Candy Machine used to create and mint the NFT.

You can find a more in depth explanation with images if you need a visual guide in this Gitbook that I'm working on. Trying to put a bunch of resources for general questions like that all in one guide.

https://sebastian-solano.gitbook.io/solana-development-bible/